# Bootstrap modal youtube video embed fullscreen with autoplay

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

> https://codepen.io/JacobLett/pen/xqpEYE

In this youtube video is automatically play when tap on button. I need one more feature it should play in landscape (full screen)mode tapped in mobile like

> https://codepen.io/immad-hamid/pen/ypxXmM

How to do it for youtube videos?
How to embed video in my website so that I can open up modal and autoplay in full screen in both mobile and computer.

Answer (score 3):

Is that what you're looking for?

```html
 <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NFWSFbqL0A0?autoplay=1" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The `?autoplay=1` query will ensure the video gets automatically played.

Replace the iframe in the second CodePen (the one with the Facebook video) with the code above.

**To have the modal open in fullscreen, the bare minimum CSS would be:**

```css
.modal-dialog {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I need it in bootstrap modal autoplay in fullscreen

Comment: Do you want to have a YouTube iframe autoplay in fullscreen? I don't think this is possible using just the queries in the link. However, you can make the modal take up the entire screen using either CSS or JS. I can update the code to include that.

Comment: Not working in mobile. I need mainly in mobile. Autoplay is not important, but full screen is important

Comment: I've added the code to make the modal fullscreen. You can also tweak padding and whatnot to make it look seamless.

Answer (score 0):

I used this In one of my project made in Django, where I had to show video via youtube link.

```
 <video controls style="width: 98.5%; height: 500px; padding-bottom:235px;" id="uploaded-video" draggable="true" small_video allow="autoplay" allowFullScreen>
            <source src="{{ listing_video.videofile.url }}" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
```

Comment: This will not work with a YouTube link. I would also advise against using magic number measurements like 98.5% or 235px.

Answer (score 0):

In order to autoplay any video you need to use the muted attribute. Along with the autoplay attribute.

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" autoPlay={true} muted>
   <source src={YouTube.com/yourlinkhere} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```